# Fetch data from web service in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, sbjson

I am developing an iOS app that should pull data from a web service. Now i have developed a basic structure and layout and implemented it to show static content.

But when i try to load data from an api with the use SBJSON Lib, it gives a lot of errors as It dose not support Automatic reference counting (ARC) which is forced by xcode5.

I Found a solution to that by disabling ARC in the whole project, but again there were a lot of errors as i did not have ant data release mechanism to free the memory space.

So Now, my question is that is some lib that can be used with automatic reference counting or use any method to use SBJSON lib but not mess up my whole project.

I am quiet new to iOS development and don't know much about available options. I have googled the issue a lot but nothing worked in my case.

Also i read about an inbuilt json lib that can b used for development (introduced from ios5 , I think!). How to use it and is it any different/ better than other 3rd party lib available.

Technology
iOS : 7 or later
xcodeversion : 5.1.1
Application : universal

Any suggestion would be a great help. 
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: The Apple JSON support is class `NSJSONSerialization`. By all means do use it.

Comment: you should check some very basic tutorials for url connection & json parsing. check this [reference link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials)

Comment: @Zaph : thanks, i ll surely apply the ways as mentioned.

Comment: @pawan : thanks , checking the link

Comment: @pawan : The [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials) is really good and got some help to develop the application futher. thanks Once   again